# Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (not code) - problem with ssh connection using private key

Tags: visual-studio, ssh, visual-studio-2022, ssh-keys, openssh

I'm trying to connect to my remote Linux machine using an SSH-RSA private key following this tutorial: [Connect to your target Linux system in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/connect-to-your-remote-linux-computer?view=msvc-170).

Facts:

1. I can successfully connect to the target using a private key with Visual Studio Code, PuTTY, WinSCP, and the WSL terminal.
2. All SSH algorithms are supported on both sides (Microsoft Visual Studio and the OpenSSH server)(Encryption, HMAC, Key exchange, Host key).
3. I can connect to the target using Microsoft Visual Studio and a normal password
4. The passphrase for the private key is empty. I also tried connecting using a key with a passphrase, but there was no difference.
5. Public ssh key is stored inside ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
6. SSH-DSA key also doesn't work

Errors:

- Host name and port: Failed to negotiate host key algorihm. Only RSA and DSA host keys are supported.
- Private key file: An error occurred connecting using private key 'path\to\the\private\key'.
- Passphrase: Passphrase invalid

[Screenshot-Microsoft Visual Studio-Connecting to the Remote System Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trLwa.png)

Answer (score -1):

Solution: Convert your ssh key with command 'ssh-keygen -p -f /path/to/key -m pem'

PS.
Read tutorials carefully :)

Comment: I DID read the tutorials carefully and the workflow still did not work. Snark is never helpful.